# What does this colon mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I learning about deep learning using *tensorflow*.

While studying the code on github I saw an unknown `:`.

I searched variously, but the error appeared in the following section, and I could not solve the error.

I don't know if this error is a problem that doesn't return a float or that `:` problem.

```
   return self.test_images_name[(batch_num % ro_num) * batch_size: (batch_num % ro_num + 1) * batch_size], \
               self.test_eye_pos_name[(batch_num % ro_num) * batch_size: (batch_num % ro_num + 1) * batch_size], \
               self.test_ref_images_name[(batch_num % ro_num) * batch_size: (batch_num % ro_num + 1) * batch_size], \
               self.test_ref_pos_name[(batch_num % ro_num) * batch_size: (batch_num % ro_num + 1) * batch_size]
```

Error message

> File
>   "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Exemplar-GAN-Eye-Inpainting-Tensorflow-master\Exemplar-GAN-Eye-Inpainting-Tensorflow-master\ExemplarGAN.py", line 154, in train
>       train_data_list, batch_eye_pos, batch_train_ex_list, batch_ex_eye_pos = self.data_ob.getNextBatch(step2, self.batch_size)
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [slice operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) being applied to the lists, it just looks odd because of the long names, and because there's a space after the colon. If you simplify a bit, it's just:

```py
i = (batch_num % ro_num) * batch_size
j = (batch_num % ro_num + 1) * batch_size

return self.test_images_name[i:j], \
       self.test_eye_pos_name[i:j], \
       self.test_ref_images_name[i:j], \
       self.test_ref_pos_name[i:j]
```

Apparently, one of these is None, so you can't index or slice it.